Mongoose middleware "remove" does not work
I am using mongoose. I have two models: user and trophies. When I delete user, I want to delete all of its trophies. I am following mongoose library and I have code like it, but it does not work:
userSchema.pre('remove', async function (next) {
  const user = this
  await Trophies.deleteMany({ owner: user._id })
  next()
})


Could you please help?
I have tried different names for middleware, "delete", "deleteMany" but it is not working for none of them.

The Model.remove method was removed in Mongoose V7 so if you are using >V6 then your pre hook won't do anything since remove() is never called during a document deletion.
It's good practice to use:
User.findByIdAndDelete(id)

or
User.findOneAndDelete({key:value})

and if you do so then on your userSchema you can register the hook on the findOneAndDelete middleware instead. That middleware fires for both findByIdAndDelete and findOneAndDelete.
It makes more sense to use a post hook for this too:
userSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function (doc) {
  await Trophies.deleteMany({ owner: doc._id })
});

